# How do I manage PR and CI pipelines in Git Flow strategy?

Tags: continuous-integration, pull-request, branching-and-merging, git-flow, branching-strategy

If I deploy to prod from the latest release branch forked from dev how can I integrate PR to review code?

Also, if I would like to run a test integration pipeline automatically when a pull request is done to link the result to the pull request and improve the code review process is it possible with this kind of branch strategy?

At the moment I have the following branch strategy:

- master
- test
- dev
- features

Features are detached from dev, then merged in dev when they are ready.
When a set of features are ready I create a PR from dev to test and my test pipeline runs and shows the result inside the PR to improve the code review process.

When code is merged into a test after PR a pipeline ships it to the test environment and another test pipeline runs to test APIs from the outside.
Then code is merged to prod and shipped to prod.

Comment: It's not clear which merge you wish to code review? Is it merging your release branch (which I think you are calling `test`) into `master`? If yes, you don't need a code review for that because `test` would always be fully ahead of `master` and already tested. You can safely merge `test` into `master` when you deploy to production.